# shell how to capture variable value

Tags: shell

I am trying to get the value of the variable(combined variable and argument)

```
 num4=$dir_$2_$3_$date
 mv test.tar $dir$2_$3_$date
  var=$1,$2,$3,$4,$HOSE,$syncsvr1,$num4
  echo $var > value.txt
```

I got all of the values inside var except num4. am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Hard do say without a [mcve], but two likely causes: **1** Quoting! Quote your variables! **2** Is the variable called `dir` or `dir_`? If you want to expand a variable followed by a `_` use curly brackets: `num4="${dir}_…"` [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) is your friend!

Comment: its dir only. its a variable for directory path. I include "_" only for space naming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this problem:

```
num4="${dir}_${2}_${3}_$date"
```